# Inserting multiple json element in MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, mongodb

I would like to have my mongoDB document in this structure...

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("578f547790ee5304306404ea"),
    "status" : " que faire?",
    "Likes" : 0,
    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-07-20T08:49:39Z"),
    "UniqueID" : "456511553",
    "screen_name" : "xtraloveable1",
    "Name" : "AmirGloir&Beauté",
    "lang" : "fr",
    "statuses_count" : 2914,
    "friends_count" : 41,
    "followers_count" : 47,
    "Description" : "Je pense donc je twitte...",
    "locationGEO" : "38000",
    "Timezone" : null,
    "Hashtags" : [ ],
    "User_Mention" : [
            "CouponNetworkFR"
    ],
    retweeted_status[
        {
            "text":"sdfsjfksdf",
            "date":"ISODate("2016-07-20T08:49:39Z")",
            "lang":"fr"
        }
    ]}
```

I tried until user_mention but I have an issue while creating "retweeted_status" array.
These information were extracted from tweets(json format)
Git file is attached here [Code Here](https://github.com/prabha123/MongoDB-Insert-issue)
Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: It inserts in this format "Retweeted_status" : [
        "status:#Damasco ha l'audio""
        "created_at:Tue Sep 27 23:09:45 BST 2016",
"lang:fr"
] Which is not a correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your Gist i found that you are appending `original_tweet_info` into `original_status`. Where the `original_tweet_info` is a string Array. What you have to do is, Append the values into `retweet_status` document.

Example:

```
            retweet_status.add("Status:"+text);
            retweet_status.add("created_at:"+dd);
            retweet_status.add("retweetCount:"+retweetCount);
            retweet_status.add("Likes:"+Likes);
```

and

Append this `retweet_status` into `ArrayList<Document> re_twts`
then append this `re_twts` into `original_status`

```
ArrayList<Document> re_twts = new ArrayList<Document>();
re_twts.append(retweet_status);
.....
....
original_status.append("Retweeted_status", re_twts);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your required data structure:
 retweeted_status:[
        {
            "text":"sdfsjfksdf",
            "date":"ISODate("2016-07-20T08:49:39Z")",
            "lang":"fr"
        }
    ]

Then your code should be like this,

```
ArrayList<String> original_tweet_info = new ArrayList<String>();
    //create document
        Document original_tweet_info_object = new Document();
        original_tweet_info_object.append("created_at:"+dd);
        original_tweet_info_object.append("retweetCount:"+retweetCount);
        original_tweet_info_object.append("Likes:"+Likes);
        original_tweet_info_object.append("TimeZone:"+timezone);

//add document in list of document
original_tweet_info.add(original_tweet_info_object);
```

original_status.append("Retweeted_status", original_tweet_info);

// Insert new_status into the labTweets collection

```
       collection.insertOne(original_status);
```

Comment: @ radhakrishnan original_tweet_info.add(original_tweet_info_object); throws me an error.

Comment: pls check code correctly, original_tweet_info is ArrayList<Document> , and original_tweet_info_object is Document , so adding Document into ArrayList<Document> , doesn't throw an error

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I used Original_tweet_info as string list. that's why it throws me an error.